# How do you add any non-specific string or text into an if statement or a find in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I was working on a timeline, I had to have it add the line, but I also had to have it reorganize itself date-wise, so I turned the dates into the format of
m/d/y (what happened that date), and tried

```
    (str(m)+'/'+str(d)+'/'+str(y)+str(''))
```

as my code but it wouldn't add the message like I wanted it to with the:
        +str('')
 and I haven't been able to find out how to import a specific text in a non-specific manner.

my full code:

```
## This was a code created by Fox on 5-14-17
import math
n=0
m=0
d=0
y=0
timeline = []
with open('dates.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        timeline.append(line.strip().split(','))
while True:
    if timeline[0] is (str(m)+'/'+str(d)+'/'+str(y)+str('')):
        n=+1
    else:
        if d<=31:
           d=+1
        elif m<=12:
            m=+1
            d=0
        elif y<2100:
            y=+1
            d=0
            m=0
        else:
            break
```

Ex:  when you have dates.txt consisting of:

9/1/1939 Offical start of WW2
12/7/1941 Pearl Harbor
10/22/22 March on Rome

The outcome wanted when ran:

[10/22/22 March on Rome,9/1/1939 Offical start of WW2,12/7/1941 Pearl Harbor]

Having it in order date-wise.

Comment: You are going to have to give us more context. Are you able to post your source code? You can use the code block formatting option to make it look nice.

Comment: are you working with [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) objects or with `str` objects?

Comment: `+str('')` is more than superfluous.